# Hello world application not working in Firefox 7.0.1

Tags: extjs

I am not able to open Hello world application in Firefox 7.0.1. I am developing this app using [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/getting_started) tutorial from Sencha documentation.When I opened Firefox Web Developer Console, I found following CSS errors :

```
Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'cursor'.  Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Unknown property '-moz-outline'.  Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Expected color but found 'null'.  Error in parsing value for 'color'.   Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Expected color but found 'null'.  Error in parsing value for  'border-bottom-color'.  Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft'.  Declaration  dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'border-bottom-left-radius'.  Declaration  dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for '-moz-border-radius-bottomright'.   Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'border-bottom-right-radius'.  Declaration  dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for '-moz-border-radius-topleft'.  Declaration  dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'border-top-left-radius'.  Declaration  dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for '-moz-border-radius-topright'.  Declaration  dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Error in parsing value for 'border-top-right-radius'.  Declaration  dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Unknown property 'behavior'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
Expected color but found 'invert'.  Error in parsing value for  'outline'.  Declaration dropped. @  http://localhost:8080/ExtJs/HelloWorld/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css:1
```

I would like to know why these many errors are coming and how to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did the same thing in the same version of Firefox (and in version 8.01) and I am getting the same Warnings (not Errors) as you.

Apparently it is an old issue:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?10956-Solved-css-warnings-feedviewer-in-firefox-2

Comment: My problem is resolved now. I was getting those errors because of my stupid mistake. I had given incorrect name of folder which contained extjs files.